# Object to String always gives me null

Tags: java, tostring

Fundamental question, and I've tried to apply several other related questions to figure it out, but this always comes back as null.

```
public class Consultant {

public Name name;
String lastName;
String firstName;
String middleName;

public Consultant (Name name){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = name.getLastName();
    this.firstName = name.getFirstName();
    this.middleName = name.getMiddleName();
}

public Name getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setFirstName(){
    firstName = name.getFirstName();
}

public void setMiddleName(){
    middleName = name.getMiddleName();
}

public void setLastName(){
    lastName = name.getLastName();
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return lastName + ", " + firstName + " " + middleName;
}
```

}

Why I try to use this anywhere as a print out, all I see is null, null null. I've tried adjusting the code several times to no avail.

Here is the test class snippet that runs successfully, just returns null values for the name:

```
public void consultantTimeToStringTest() {
    String fName = "Test";
    String lName = "Dude";
    Name contact = new Name(lName, fName);
    Consultant testConsultant = new Consultant(contact);
    System.out.println(testConsultant.toString());
```

Here is the Name class as well:

```
public class Name {

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

public Name(){

}

public Name(String lastName, String firstName){

}

public Name(String lastName, String firstName, String middleName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Name other = (Name) obj;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    if (middleName == null) {
        if (other.middleName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!middleName.equals(other.middleName))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public String getMiddleName(){
    return middleName;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((middleName == null) ? 0 : middleName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){

}

public void setLastName(String lastName){

}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName){

}

public String toString(){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    result.append(lastName);
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you assigning values to firstName,middleName and lastName? if you don't assign anything by default string fields will be null.

Comment: Tangentially, why are you duplicating state? The "set" methods are particularly confusing as they just do what the constructor has already done.

Comment: How do you create your Name and Consultant objects?

Comment: Are you set the firstName, middleName and lastName ?

Comment: Could you please update your question to include the name class (only parts of it if it's really big) and a print out of the "name" that you pass into your Consultant object?

Comment: In my test class I am providing the instantiated Consultant object with a Name object, which I then use to try and give the name values actual values within Consultant.

Comment: Stick `System.out.println` everywhere.

Comment: The only possibility is you write `Name` class for wrong. `name.getFirstName();`, `name.getMiddleName();` and `name.getMiddleName();` all return null.

Comment: Your "setXxxxName" methods for Name don't work.

Comment: @PaulBellora my redundancy is a result of my novice padwan status. Just trying to do anything I can to make it work.

Comment: Strip away all the redundancy -- in redundancy there be dragons.  KISS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Consultant` class has a single constructor that takes in `Name` as a parameter.

When you instantiate `Consultant`, you must be passing in a `Name` object that has null for `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`.

I would recommend tagging the debugger on a line right before you new-up a `Consultant` object and check the `Name` object passed in and see if there are any values for `Name.firstName`, etc.

I would also add a breakpoint in the constructor of `Consultant` to watch the values for `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName` be set.

**UPDATE**

You just posted the code for `Name` and your constructor is doing nothing.  Your code reads:

```
public Name(String lastName, String firstName){

}
```

It should read

```
public Name(String lastName, String firstName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize name as:

```
Name contact = new Name(lName, fName);
```

But you didn't do anything in

```
public Name(String lastName, String firstName){

}
```

and in your `Name` class,

```
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
```

are all initialized as `null`s. So when you call

```
public void setFirstName(){
    firstName = name.getFirstName();
}

public void setMiddleName(){
    middleName = name.getMiddleName();
}

public void setLastName(){
    lastName = name.getLastName();
}
```

in your `Consultant` class, they get all `null`.